# Is it possible to install knative on docker for mac

Tags: kubernetes, knative-serving

I followed this [guide](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/install/Knative-with-any-k8s.md) and everything started running.

```
kubectl get pods --namespace=knative-serving -w
NAME                          READY     STATUS            RESTARTS   AGE
activator-f98dc8dc8-r6qlg     0/2       PodInitializing   0          5m
autoscaler-7787cd648-4lwdg    2/2       Running           0          5m
controller-55f7988d59-d8zwd   1/1       Running           0          5m
webhook-5b844dfbd5-7bz84      1/1       Running           0          5m
activator-f98dc8dc8-r6qlg   2/2       Running   0         5m
```

After a few seconds, `kubectl` commands are failing with the following error.

```
kubectl get nodes
Unable to connect to the server: net/http: TLS handshake timeout
```

Is it possible to install `knative` on docker for mac kubernetes cluster?

My kubernetes version:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"11", GitVersion:"v1.11.1", GitCommit:"b1b29978270dc22fecc592ac55d903350454310a", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-07-18T11:37:06Z", GoVersion:"go1.10.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"darwin/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"10", GitVersion:"v1.10.3", GitCommit:"2bba0127d85d5a46ab4b778548be28623b32d0b0", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2018-05-21T09:05:37Z", GoVersion:"go1.9.3", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"
```

Answer (score 0):

[Knative](https://cloud.google.com/knative/) provides a set of middleware components that are essential to build modern, source-centric, and container-based applications that can run anywhere: on premises, in the cloud, or even in a third-party data center. Knative components are built on Kubernetes and codify the best practices shared by successful real-world Kubernetes-based frameworks. It enables developers to focus just on writing interesting code, without worrying about the “boring but difficult” parts of building, deploying, and managing an application.

Back to your question.

It is possible to use Knative on Docker containers mananaged by Kubernetes on MacOS environment. You may try to install it
on [Minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/).

1. Start minikube:

> minikube start --memory=8192 --cpus=4 \   --kubernetes-version=v1.10.5
>   \   --vm-driver=hyperkit \   --bootstrapper=kubeadm \
>   --extra-config=controller-manager.cluster-signing-cert-file="/var/lib/localkube/certs/ca.crt"
>   \
>   --extra-config=controller-manager.cluster-signing-key-file="/var/lib/localkube/certs/ca.key"
>   \
>   --extra-config=apiserver.admission-control="LimitRanger,NamespaceExists,NamespaceLifecycle,ResourceQuota,ServiceAccount,DefaultStorageClass,MutatingAdmissionWebhook"

2. Install Istio with NodePort feature:

> curl -L 
>   https://raw.githubusercontent.com/knative/serving/v0.1.1/third_party/istio-0.8.0/istio.yaml
>   \   | sed 's/LoadBalancer/NodePort/' \   | kubectl apply -f -
>
> ```
>  kubectl label namespace default istio-injection=enabled
> ```

3. Monitor the Istio components until all of the components show a STATUS of Running or Completed:

> kubectl get pods -n istio-system --watch

4. Install knative for resource limited environment:

> curl -L
>   https://github.com/knative/serving/releases/download/v0.1.1/release-lite.yaml
>   \   | sed 's/LoadBalancer/NodePort/' \   | kubectl apply -f -

5. Monitor the Knative components until all of the components show a STATUS of Running:

> kubectl get pods -n knative-serving --watch

Comment: I followed the steps mentioned and still getting the same error.
 kubectl  apply -f  service.yaml
error: unable to recognize "service.yaml": Get https://192.168.99.100:8443/api?timeout=32s: net/http: TLS handshake timeout

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's absolutely possible to run Knative on Docker for Mac. I've assembled [specific instructions](https://github.com/knative/docs/blob/master/install/Knative-with-Docker-for-Mac.md) in the upstream documentation repository.

Make sure you update Docker for Mac to be on one of the later versions. Knative meanwhile needs Kubernetes 1.12+.

Comment: That link is not available now. Any update on the link ?

Comment: These days, there's nothing special about Docker for Mac anymore. The general installation instructions at https://knative.dev/docs/install/any-kubernetes-cluster/ should be just fine.